# Making absolute list of text

Tags: css, css-float, absolute

I have a list of text in my website that looks like this:

[image]

My goal is if the user hover one of those text, an image would pop out related to that text that is hovered over. Something like this:

[image]

But instead, I get something like this that creates some spaces between texts:

[image]

Comment: Come up with a short example that can reproduce the problem. Without any codes, your question is pretty much not a real question.

Comment: A JQuery [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/N7QNQ/).

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:absolute` on the image element should stop this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Set your list item to `position: relative` and the image to `position: absolute`. Then position it as desired. (E.g. something like `top: 0; left: 100%;` )

Answer (score 0):

Just use the position relative and absolute, for exemple :

```
li { position : relative; }
li img { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 100%; }
```